# Mediawiki Cite Extension does not work

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Basically what the question says. I've installed Mediawiki v1.24.4 onto my site and am trying to create a references list for an article. The default Cite extension is installed in .../[domain]/extensions/Cite - this version of Cite was installed by the Mediawiki software automatically, so it should be working.

The manual installation instructions say to add `wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );` to the Localsettings.php file. I tried that, but got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wfLoadExtension() in /home/[web_host_username]/ on line 136

When I add the `<ref>[text goes here]</ref>` and `<references />` markup to the article currently, the tags stay as plain text.

I did read the [question][2] asked about putting the Cite extension into the editing toolbar, but this is a different issue where I can't even get it to work by manually adding the markup.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions you're following apply to MediaWiki 1.25 and newer.  From the Cite extension page:

> To users running MediaWiki 1.24 or earlier: The instructions above
>   describe the new way of installing extensions using wfLoadExtension(),
>   since MediaWiki 1.25. 
>   If you need to install this extension in earlier
>   versions, instead of wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );, you need to use:
>   require_once "$IP/extensions/Cite/Cite.php";